# How do I add this value to an Array and it stays in the script

Tags: perl

I want to add a command that adds numbers to the array.

This is what i have exactly:

```
my $ownerids = ('374867065');
```

Then later in the script i have this:

```
if($ownerids == $spl2[0]){
    if (index($message, "!adduser") != -1) {
        $msg = $spl[1];
        $send = "<m t=\"User Added $msg\" u=\"$botid\"  />\0";
        $socket->send($send);
        push (my $ownerids, "$msg");
    }
}
```

I am on a chatbox and this is a chatbot, i want to make it when i say !adduser (thereid) it adds them to a list and they can use the bot commands, and also i want a Delete User, If you can help this will be MUCH appretiated.

Comment: There brackets arn't lined up on here but on the script they actually are.

Comment: Don't use TAB characters when posting to SO.

Comment: Okay, If you can help or know someone who can help it will be much appretiated

Comment: Don't use `my` inside the `if`, it declares a local variable that's not the same as the one outside the block.

Answer (score 2):

If you want ownerids to be an array, then you must prefix it with a `@`

```
my @ownerids = ('374867065');
```

Then to add an element, you can [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html)

```
push @ownerids, "$msg";
```

However,  you're going to need to fix your other references to `@ownerids` so it's treated like an array.  For example, your first if looks like it's intending to see if `$spl2[0]` is an owner.  If that's the case, then you'll need to [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) the array:

```
if(grep {$_ == $spl2[0]} @ownerids) {
```

Comment: Say for an example the array was: my @ownerids = ('374867065'); After that command and i typed !adduser 100 would it change to my ATownerids = ('374867065','100');  ???

Comment: Had to use AT because can't use more than 1 @

Comment: I don't know if it would properly [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) `100` to the end of `@ownerids` because I can't see your whole code, and don't know the meaning of data structures like `@spl` or `@spl2`.  All I'm saying is that what you were doing before wasn't going to do it, but that making the changes I proposed would be a step toward fixing the inherant flaws in your code.

Comment: Would you be willing to help me through team viewer, so you can control and see my entire script, i cant post on here because it's privite and many people on this chatbox dream to have it.

Comment: Some other time perhaps.  It's the end of my Friday, so it's time to leave the office and head out.  The next time I'll be online is Saturday, 2:30pm PDT.